# How to detect empty areas on canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to check is there any empty areas on canvas in FabricJS and display alert. I think this can be done by detecting pixels on canvas but I have no idea. How to do that?

Comment: Not many details in your question. FabricJS does not offer to fetch the pixel information for you like native html5 canvas does with `getImageData`. You might have to get a reference to your underlying  FabricJS canvas (which is a native html5 canvas) and then do .getImageData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get pixeldata you need access to the 2D context. To do that in FabricJS you have to call `StaticCanvas.getContext();` the standard fabric canvas will have this in the prototype chain.[Fabric StaticCanvas doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html)

From there to get the pixel data use

```
var ctx = yourCanvas.getContext(); // your canvas is the Fabric canvas
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

To access a single pixel you have to calculate the index and then retrieve the 4 bytes that make a pixel, one byte each for red, green, blue, and alpha.

Function to get a pixel once you have the pixelData.

```
// pixelData is the pixel data, x and y are the pixel location
function getPixel(pixelData,x,y){
    // make sure the coordinate is in bounds
    if(x < 0 || x >= pixelData.width || y < 0 || y >= pixelData.height){
         return {
            r : 0,
            g : 0,
            b : 0,
            a : 0 
         };
   }
   // get the index of the pixel. Floor the x and y just in case they are not ints
   var index = Math.floor(x) * 4 + Math.floor(y) * 4 * pixelData.width;
   // return the pixel data
   return {
       r : pixelData.data[index++],
       g : pixelData.data[index++],
       b : pixelData.data[index++],
       a : pixelData.data[index++] 
   };
}
```

That should help you find the empty areas. Note that when alpha is zero, red, green, and blue will also be zero. The function above is very slow so it is not intended for use in your problem, it just shows how to get a pixel from the pixelData and how to get a pixel address (index).

Comment: @MarkE I just tried it on firefox, chrome and edge, before render `rgba = 0xffffffff` then `comp = "xor"` then draw an all white Image and reading the same pixel I get `rgba = 0x00000000` From memory the standard requires a zero alpha to be matched with zero for all the other channels.

Comment: Ok, I probably remembered wrong ... I could have sworn a while back  XOR bit me in this regard. Thanks for checking :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you wanna track click on an empty area, you can check event.subTargets

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
  if (!event.subTargets.length) {
    //do stuff... 
  }
})
```